# Windows "system service", not "web service" performance

Tags: performance, image-processing, service, operating-system, nt

We have an image processing workflow product. Typically 10,000->100,000 images can be run though our processing in a job. More than one job may be pending.

Currently, all the image processing is performed in our home grown imaging library, a managed C++ library,  .NET compatible.  It is run in the user’s application space.  What I mean by that is that if you log on as “PeteSmith” the images will be run on Pete Smiths’ account.

Currently, we only allow one instance of this image processing at a time.  Customers are asking us for a new version, one that allows more than one instance to run at the same time, so the question of how we do this is now something we are examining.

The idea of getting processing off the “users account” and using a “system account” to do the processing in the background is appealing.  It is appealing,  because of the way windows services are naturally managed by OS events like logging in and logging out and other system resource utilization events alarms.

It appears to me that all we would need to do is manage a small number of well-defined events, well documented by Microsoft.
That’s all nice and wonderful. But what I need to understand is what going to a service implantation for our image processing code means for performance, from our customer’s point of view. 
In their view, they need more processed, faster.

QUESTION How I should think about tradoffs:

1)  Using a service to run a job vs. running N different “instances” of the software running only on Pete Smith (the users’) account?

2)  Allowing N number of services to run N different jobs (no cross talk needed) in comparison to running N different “instances” of the software running only on Pete Smith (the users’) account?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the image processing requires a certain amount of CPU and IO resources for the processing. That amount does not change by fiddling with how and where you start your process.

The difference between service or not should be governed by the required usage pattern. If you want the application to go on processing images automatically regardless if anyone is logged on you should run as a service, but if the usage is more like "choose an image, start processing and wait for the result" style you should go for a client app.

It is not entirely clear why your customer wants to run multiple instances. Is it because they want to have one instance do the heavy processing work while they configure the processing for the other? Or do they want to run multiple instances because the processing is heavy and they want to run multiple in parallel?

In both those cases I would consider running the calculation(s) on a background thread in the application. If it is not possible to use threads (maybe due to some global shared state in the library) my second best bet would be to start each processing in a new process and wait for the result on the main process.

Comment: "The difference between service or not should be governed by the required usage pattern" -> agreed.